# adaptivecards nodejs examples for botbuilder

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have a bot built using nodejs v3 sdk and I am trying to adaptivecards to make UI experience richer. Is there a goto place I can start with ? Some example will be good to for starters. `[https://adaptivecards.io/][1]`

Answer (score 1):

The Samples section on the [Adaptive Cards Website](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/) is a good place to start to see the art of the possible with cards. If your using JavaScript for your Bot like I did the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) for adding Rich Card attachments to the Botframework is useful and [this Article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/06/28/getting-started-with-adaptive-cards-and-the-bot-framework/) has some good examples of showing ways to insert data into fields of Adaptive Cards, which we find useful with loading in answers from QnA Maker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's really helpful. I have one more final question & I think it will clear all the confusion.

I read through  documenst on adaptive case usages for bot developers.

some examples usages nodejs library adaptivecards
some examples addAttachment() method on bot builder
to Add rich card attachments to messages.

What is the best way and right way to use adaptivecards?

Do I need to use npm library for bot builder nodejs v3 or/and v4 ?
Can we rely on addAttachment() and never use npm ?

I am able to use adaptivecards in my V3 botbuilder w/o npm library.

Comment: You should be able to rely on addAttachment to send adaptive cards, its what I used and it worked great.